# Compilation Error: AnnotationName expected instead

Tags: android, eclipse, password-protection

I'm trying to password protect an activity on its own, and I'm having some problems. There are some errors in the code.

```
import com.foo.avanos.AvanosActivity;
import com.foo.avanos.R;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;;

public class ChangePassword extends AvanosActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button ChangePasswordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ChangePasswordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }

        Button EnterButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //Below, it's telling me 'Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead'
        EnterButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick2(View v) {
                EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.layout.password);
                SharedPreferences prefs = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE);
                String NewPassword = prefs.getString("password","");
                String CurrentPassword = prefs.getString("password","NewPassword");
                if(NewPassword.equals(CurrentPassword)){
                    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                    edit.putString("password",passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                    edit.commit();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Passwords do not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                //Below, it's telling me 'Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

First of all, I would like to know if I'm doing this correctly. If I'm not, please guide me in doing it right.

Comment: What errors are you having? What is written in your Logcat?

Comment: ^the name of my activity

Answer (score 0):

End your setOnclickListener with a `);` it is not ended hence you are getting the compilation errors.

```
ChangePasswordButton.setOnClickListener{
   public void onClick2(View v) {
        //code goes here
   }
});
```

same is the case with

```
EnterButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
}
});
```

And use Onclick not onClick2

Assign the click listeners to a variable and then do a setOnclickListener. It will be readable.

Comment: Also, All your buttons have the same id

Answer (score 0):

You have a second semi colon at the bottom of your context. Remove it adn try again.